# Is there a way to animate a <div> or <p> when its height changes because of a change in the html value?

Tags: html, css, reactjs

Hello this is for a React/Gatsby website i'm working on.
I'm searching for a way to animate the child paragraph of a div using only CSS transition:

```
<div>
   <p>{excerpt}</p>
</div>
```

Where `excerpt` is a variable i'm changing via Javascript when the cursor hovers the parent `<div>`.

This is the simplified React component. `excerpt` is a React state:

```
import React, { useState } from 'react'

const PostExcerpt = ({ post, featured }) => {
  const [excerpt, setExcerpt] = useState(post.shortExcerpt)

  const handleHover = (event, hover) => {
    event.preventDefault()
    if (hover) setExcerpt(post.longExcerpt)
    else setExcerpt(post.shortExcerpt)
  }

  return (
    <div
      onPointerOver={(event) => {
        handleHover(event, true)
      }}
      onPointerOut={(event) => {
        handleHover(event, false)
      }}
    >
      <p>{excerpt}</p>
    </div>
  )
}
export default PostExcerpt
```

The height of the `<p>` is adjusted automatically when content changes and i would like to animate the height change.

[How can I transition height: 0; to height: auto; using CSS?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3508605/how-can-i-transition-height-0-to-height-auto-using-css) doesn't apply because the height of my element is always set to `auto`. It simply changes because it follows content dimensions.

Comment: Could you put up a Stackoverflow snippet which shows what you have so far, including the JS that updates the paragraph element? Also what property(s) do you want to animate?

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How can I transition height: 0; to height: auto; using CSS?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3508605/how-can-i-transition-height-0-to-height-auto-using-css)

Comment: I added the whole React code i have so far, where you can see how i change the `excerpt` value when hovering the parent `div`